# how to Deploy APK on buildfire

Tags: buildfire

Please I want to find out how to deploy my APK on buildfire.
Also, can I use ReactNative on Buildfire?

```
<pre>
    You <em>cannot</em> use Markdown here
</pre>
```

Comment: Do you already have an APK/AAB? Or are you asking how to I create an APK using BuildFire? BuildFire apps will automatically create an IPA and APK for you alongside a PWA (if configured).

Comment: As for React Native, this is a misconception on how BuildFire's SDK works. The whole Idea is that you wouldn't need Iconic or ReactNative to build your app. That being said you can use React when building on the BuildFire SDK

Comment: @Daniel_Madain I already have an APK and I want to host it on Buildfire

Comment: so can you help me with the procedures on how to host the APK on buildfire

Comment: Chidebere, that's like saying "I built a React Native APK can I move it over to Ionic" That's not how it works. Yes, both produce APKs but they are fundamentally different architectures. You can post over the App Key to override in Google Play but you would need to rebuild it in BuildFire. That doesn't mean yo have to through all you code away. But I couldn't tell you what you can keep without seeing the code. However, if you have logic written in JS then its safe to say you can port it over.